# How to check if certain object is locked in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, mutex

For synchronized access on an object, the following pattern is common:

```
Object lock = new Object();

@GuardedBy("lock")
Object sharedObject;
```

Where lock is used as synchronized(lock) {}. The annotation is nice but it's not enforced. I would like to do something like this:

```
class SyncedReference<T> {

  Object lock;

  T value;

  SyncedReference(Object lock) {}

  T get() {
    if (!isLocked(lock)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return value;
  }

  boolean isLocked() {
    // How to do this?
  }
}
```

My question is how to implement the isLocked() method?

Comment: Intrinsic locks in Java are _[reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)_. Don't bother to _test_ the lock in the `get` method: Just _lock_ it. If `get()` was called in a thread that already had the object locked, then nothing special will happen.

Comment: "I would like to do something like this" - it's a wrong wish.

Comment: If you want to be able to do this, you need to use the classes from `java.util.concurrent.locks`.

Comment: Alexei, could you elaborate? I would like to learn about best practices.